# onclick ScrollBottom dentro de "table"

Tags: javascript

Quando clicar em contatar o formulário se expande, no entanto o usuário tem de rolar o scroll para vizualizar o mesmo. Preciso fazer com que ao clicar em contatar automaticamente seja enviado para o fim da "table".

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="table1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:100%; height:330px; overflow-x: hidden;">
         <table id="table2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" >
           <tr>
             <td>

<a role="button" onclick="ScrollToBottom()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="display: block; width: 100%; border-radius: 0px;"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Contatar</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <form ....>
</div>
             </td>
           </tr>
         </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: para o fim da table? não entendi, seu código está incompleto e não dá para entender exatamente o que ocorre e o que deveria ser

Answer (score 0):

Script para expandir

```
    function toggleTable() {
    var lTable = document.getElementById("collapseTable");
    lTable.style.display = (lTable.style.display == "table") ? "none" : "table";
}
```

Html

A utilização de âncoras permite a inserção de marcações em determinados pontos de um documento, possibilitando o deslocamento direto para estes pontos, através da criação de referências.

O recurso da criação de âncoras é bastante utilizado como índice de documentos, facilitando o deslocamento do leitor diretamente para um ponto desejado.

Um link pode ao mesmo tempo, referenciar e ser uma marcação. Essa prática é utilizada em páginas demasiadamente extensas possibilitando que o usuário se desloque do início para o fim do documento ou vice-versa. Como valor deste atributo devemos informar o nome da marcação, precedida do sinal #, caso esta marcação pertença à mesma página da referência.  `href="#Bottom"`

Destino: A marcação será o objeto alvo de uma referência.

Uma marcação de âncora é definida utilizando o atributo (name) que receberá como valor o nome pela qual esta marcação será referenciada.  `<a name="Bottom"></a>`

Ao se clicar no link que faz referência a esta marcação, será dado um salto para este ponto da página onde foi inserida esta marcação.

> Portanto coloque essa marcação no local exato que você desejar

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="table1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <div style="width:100%; height:330px; overflow-x: hidden;">
         <table id="table2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" >
           <tr>
             <td>

<a role="button" onclick="toggleTable();" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="display: block; width: 100%; border-radius: 0px;"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#Bottom" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Contatar</a>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
<a name="Bottom"></a>
<table id="collapseTable" border="0" style="display:none">
<tr>
<td>
  <form>

  </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
             </td>
           </tr>
         </table>  
       </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```